# How can I define an ACL for a JMS Client who wants to publish directly to a queue?

Tags: solace

I have a EMS client who currently publishes directly to a queue (A.B.C).

They are now migrating to Solace.

I can define a queue for the client on the solace broker named A.B.C, but what should I put in the ACL Profile on the publish tab? Should I used the internal queue name #P2P/QUE/A.B.C or should I defined it as A.B.C?

Answer (score 0):

To control direct publishing to queues, you can use the topic pattern #P2P/QUE/A.B.C in your ACL profile.